# How to get the PATH variable on the remote machines with mpirun?

Tags: linux, bash, path, environment-variables, mpi

I've tried

```
mpirun -n $N_HOSTS -host $MPI_HOSTS echo $PATH
```

But this way, it prints me the PATH variable from the launching machine, rather than each machine printing the `$PATH` variable for itself. The substitution happens on the launching machine.

When I run either of

```
mpirun -n $N_HOSTS -host $MPI_HOSTS echo \$PATH
mpirun -n $N_HOSTS -host $MPI_HOSTS echo '$PATH'
```

The substitution doesn't happen on either host.

How to make each machine return its own `PATH` variable?

Comment: Write a shell script and `mpirun` that.

Comment: mpirun bash -c 'echo $PATH'

Answer (score 1):

You could `mpirun` a shell for expanding `$PATH`, but launching a shell involves reading rc files so the result might be inaccurate. I would use a command that can output environment variables directly, like `env` or `awk`:

```bash
mpirun -n "$N_HOSTS" -host "$MPI_HOSTS" awk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["PATH"]}'
```